# How to Monitor AzureDataFactory pipelines through .net code

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-monitoring

I have multiple pipelines in adf. How to monitor them using Program, to get the status of all the pipelines. The difficulty I am facing, I am not sure **where to find the applicationID and authenticationKey for that DataFactory**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to generate the application ID and application key by creating a new application in Azure active directory. Once created then you have to assign the role to that app.
you can go through following link to get generate the application id and application key: [Create azure active directory application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal)

For monitoring, there are various ways to monitor the pipeline by using the the powershell script, .NET SDK or Azure portal.
Please check the following link to monitor pipeline using .NET SDK:[Monitor and manage ADF v1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/v1/data-factory-monitor-manage-app)

Hope this helps,
Jai

Comment: I saw that code on the Microsoft Website, But that did not help!

Comment: Could you please explain what were you expecting from that code? i think it gives you pretty much information about ADF pipleine activity.

Comment: I want code to monitor the pipeline, How much data is send, time taken, records etc.